# Support for utf16 with ms xml 6.0

Tags: vba, excel, msxml, utf

I'm scrapping data from a site in French. I'm using MS XML 6.0, some letters are not being recognized correctly 
(é for example)

Code:

```
Dim xml_obj As XMLHTTP
Set xml_obj = New XMLHTTP
xml_obj.Open "GET", "http://www.emploi.nat.tn/fo/Fr/global.php?page=146&menu1=&FormLinks_Sorting=1&FormLinks_Sorted=&num_page=0&limit=500&numpage=1", False
xml_obj.send
Dim htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
htmldoc.body.innerHTML = xml_obj.responseText
```

[image]

responseText is coded in UTF-8. Any workaround?

Comment: Please share code and data to repro...

Comment: @CindyMeister: I've added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to decode the page since the encoding is `windows-1256`. Then write the html directly in the document and not in the body:

```
Sub UsageExample()

    Dim req As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60  ' Microsoft XML, v6.0 '
    req.Open "GET", "http://www.emploi.nat.tn/fo/Fr/global.php?page=146&menu1=&FormLinks_Sorting=1&FormLinks_Sorted=&num_page=0&limit=500&numpage=1", False
    req.Send

    Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument     ' Microsoft HTML Object Library '
    WriteDocument doc, req.responseBody, "windows-1256"

End Sub

Private Sub WriteDocument(document As Object, data, charset As String)
    Dim stream As New ADODB.stream   ' Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library '
    stream.Open
    stream.Type = 1
    stream.Write data
    stream.Position = 0
    stream.Type = 2
    stream.charset = charset

    document.Open
    document.Write stream.ReadText
    document.Close

    stream.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: perfect this is exactly what i'm looking for!